# El Servidor de Rails no arranca

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Buen dia a todo,

Me encuentro aprendiendo Rails, estoy intentando correr mi primera aplicacion, para esto debo arrancar el Servidor de Rails, pero me vota Error.

Estuve Mirando en Google y encontre que era por que faltaban cosas de JavaScript, por eso intalle Node JS, pero aun no funciona, este es el Error.

---

```
C:\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxxxx\blog>rails server
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:77:in `binwrite': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/blog/tmp/cache/bootsnap-load-path-cache.8916.40792.tmp (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:77:in `dump_data'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:55:in `commit_transaction'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:47:in `transaction'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/cache.rb:130:in `push_paths_locked'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/cache.rb:113:in `block in reinitialize'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/cache.rb:107:in `synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/cache.rb:107:in `reinitialize'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/cache.rb:14:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:33:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:33:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:24:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:33:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/blog/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
        from C:/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/blog/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: existe la carpeta `C:/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/blog/tmp/cache/` ?

Comment: Si estas aprendiendo Rails ¿existe alguna razón de peso por la cual estés usando la gema `bootsnap`? Por lo que sale en [la documentacion](https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap#usage) solo funciona en macOS y Linux, asi que es probable que ese error sea porque estas corriendo la aplicación desde Windows. Te recomendaría sacar esa gema y no complicarte tanto desde un inicio si tan solo estás aprendiendo Rails.

Comment: El gema bootsnap se genera automatico, cuando ejecuto el comando rails server